# C#/C++: Запуск приложения и перехват его обращений к файловой системе

Tags: c#, c++, файловая-система, io

Необходимо запускать приложение и перехватывать его I/O обращения к определенной папке и файлам внутри, а затем, в зависимости от определенных условий, подменять пути.

Программы типа Mod Organizer могут запускать почти любые приложения как дочерние и подменять папку `Data` у Skyrim/Oblivion. В итоге, сначала файл будет искаться в папке `mods` Mod Organizer-а, а затем уже в папке игры.

По сути, мне нужно реализовать похожий механизм для другой игры.

Насколько я вижу по [исходному коду](https://github.com/TanninOne/modorganizer/), MO достигает цели чуть ли не 3 разными путями: `hook.dll`, `proxy.dll` и как-то сам по себе.

При этом, насколько я понимаю, MO не знает точных адресов функций в asm-коде приложений. Так как многие вспомогательные программы, помимо Скайрима могут быть запущены через него.

Мне уже предлагали использовать 'File System Filter Drivers', но этот способ мне не подходит.

(Пожалуйста, без троллинга. Если минусуете - просьба пояснить причину, чтобы мои будущие вопросы были более корректными)

Comment: Перехват API используйте.

Comment: А можно конкретнее?

Comment: Конкретнее что? Назвать технологию? Найти вам примеры реализации? Или список API?

Comment: Первые 2 пункта. Обычно это является ответом

Comment: Технология называется "перехват API", куда конкретнее? Гугл успешно ищет статьи и примеры по ней.

Comment: Удалось найти решение? Пожалуйста опубликуйте, что получилось. А то у меня сходная задача, и пока не знаю с чего начать, а так хоть какая-то зацепка

Comment: К сожалению, не удалось